# KDB Q and jupyterlab not using slaves on peach

Tags: kdb, jupyter-lab

I am running a jupyter notebook (3.6) and I have 20 slaves enabled on startup using

```
"env":{"JUPYTERQ_SERVERARGS":"s-20"}
```

If I check this in the notebook it looks all good

```
\s
20i
```

However when I run a parallel process, e.g.,

```
\t:100 {sqrt (200000?x) xexp 1.7} peach 10?1.0
```

I can see that all slaves use the same cpu.

If I run the same command in a q session started from the command line using the same q binary that I specify in my runkernel .py it distributes the slaves across all available cpus.

Does anyone have an idea why jupyterlab q session would only use 1 cpu?

EDIT:
Thanks Callum and Terry for pointing me to taskset. So, initially the taskset was set to mask 8000000. I changed that

```
system "taskset -cp 30-40 ",(string .z.i)
"pid 193048's current affinity list: 27"
"pid 193048's new affinity list: 30-40"
```

and re-ran the process above. Now all the tasks run still on cpu 28 (that was the cpu used before, despite the mask setting it to 27). I also tried to set the affinity for the jupyter lab itself but that doesn't have any effect on this either.

Comment: Are you using `taskset` when starting up either the kdb jupyterlab processes? Using `taskset` is generally how you ensure a kdb process works over many/specific cpus

Comment: If your running on linux, then you can use the following in a jupyter notebook to check the taskset easily q)system "taskset -p ",string .z.i. If you are running on windows you can use something like the process monitor and manually find the jupyter lab

Comment: chrise, did you resolve this issue in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying your server args differently, they get parsed out as

```
SERVERARGS:getenv`JUPYTERQ_SERVERARGS
```

So try specifying them as follows

```
"env":{"JUPYTERQ_SERVERARGS":"-s 20"}
```